# Cannot draw this diagram using tikz-cd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I'm having a lot of problem in drawing a diagram of the form

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item \textbf{The Tower Property}
  \begin{tikzcd}
   L \arrow[hook]{u} \\
   K \arrow[hook]{u} \\
   k \arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[bend left][dotted]{uu} 
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{itemize}
```

My intention was to draw a tower consisting of L, K and k linked by arrows and such that one arrow starts at k and goes up curved and dotted to L.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first row does not need an arrow pointing up since there is none above it in your code.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \textbf{The Tower Property}
  \begin{tikzcd}
   L \\%\arrow[hook]{u}  \\
   K \arrow[hook]{u}  \\
   k \arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[bend left,dotted]{uu}
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a really dumb mistake. I need to sleep more.